# Haproxy http to https redirect host header

Tags: haproxy

I'm doing the following to redirect non-https traffic to https:

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

Which works great, however if a user injects a `Host` header they are redirected to that header rather than the target on an https connection.

**E.g.**

```
Request: http://example.com
Host Header: maliciousexample.com
```

**Expected:**

Redirect to https://example.com

**Actual:**

Redirect to https://maliciousexample.com

Is it possible to replace the `Host` header with the target URI or failing that, check that the `Host` header is a domain I have configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up doing a list of domains in a file:

```
http-request allow  if { hdr_beg(host) -f /etc/haproxy/domains.cfg }
http-request deny

redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `http-request redirect location https://example.com code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }` instead and forget malicious input.
If you care for request URI then you can use `capture.req.uri` like `http-request redirect location https://example.com%[capture.req.uri] code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }`.
You can also check for `Host` header if you have more domains in one frontend (but why would you?):

```
acl host_1 hdr(host) -i example1.com
acl host_2 hdr(host) -i example2.com
http-request redirect location https://example1.com if !{ ssl_fc } host_1
http-request redirect location https://example2.com if !{ ssl_fc } host_2
```